# Not getting JSON response

Tags: android, json

I have the following code for "POST" request where, I have an API and parameters.
But, here I am getting no response and no error also. plz help me.

```
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, List<NameValuePair> params)       throws Exception {      
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            Log.d("URL :", url);
            Log.d("params :", params.toString());
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
           Log.d("InputStreem :", is.toString());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            Log.d("BufferedReader :", reader.toString());
                  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                  String line = null;
                  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                  }
                  is.close();
                  jsonResponse = sb.toString();
            System.out.println("Respose :"+jsonResponse);//Here Resonse: "nothing"
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
        }
        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jsonData = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
        }
        // return JSON String
        return jsonData;
    }
```

Comment: You must run your code in another `thread`. what is your `httpResponse` ?

Comment: Have you tried doing the POST with a REST client from your PC's browser? Does that return anything?

Comment: When I'm printing jsonResponse, it showing nothing.

Comment: check `List<NameValuePair> params` is not *null* and try to open the url in `REST CLIENT` or `POSTMAN` in ur browser

Comment: Yes, I opened my url in REST client and I'm getting the result. But, when i print the response, in logcat it showing nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Define JSON-Class. Example:

`

```
 public class JSONParser {

        static InputStream is = null;
        static JSONObject jObj = null;
        static String json = "";

        // constructor
        public JSONParser() {

        }

        public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

            // Making HTTP request
            try {
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                json = sb.toString();
                Log.e("JSON", json);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            // try parse the string to a JSON object
            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

            // return JSON String
            return jObj;

        } }
```

2. Define Functions-Class which contains all the functions that your app will have to communicate with server. Example:

   public class UserFunctions {

   ```
   private JSONParser jsonParser;

   // URL of the API
   private static String functionURL = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/.../";

   // TAG to determine which function/query should be executed on serverside
   // e.g. with IF-ELSE
   private static String function_tag = "getData";

   // Constructor
   public UserFunctions() {
       jsonParser = new JSONParser();
   }

   /**
    * FUNCTION GetSomeData
    **/

   // Here you can define functions, and give parameters (if you need)
   // and catch those on serverside with POST as their names
   // you defined in qoutes, in this example you could catch the 2 parameters
   // with
   // $email = $_POST['email']; and $password = $_POST['password']; (assumed
   // you use PHP)

   public JSONObject functionGetData(String parameter1, String parameter2) {
       // Building Parameters
       List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
       params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", function_tag));
       params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", parameter1));
       params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", parameter1));
       JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(functionURL, params);
       return json;
   }}
   ```
3. Use AsynchTask to fetch json data. Example:

   private class FetchDataTask extends
               AsyncTask {

   ```
       String parameter1, parameter2;

       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
           super.onPreExecute();
           // Define variables here (if needed), that will be commited to
           // function/method in
           // doInBackground() as parameters

       }

       @Override
       protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

           UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();

           JSONObject json = userFunction.functionGetData(parameter1,
                   parameter2);

           return json;

       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

           try {

               // Catch data from JSON
               // Create JSON object and get it by calling method
               // getString("data")
               // on serverside json:
               // $response["jsonObj"]["data"] = $SQL_result['columnXY'];

               JSONObject json_object = json.getJSONObject("jsonObj");

               String data = json_object.getString("data");

           } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();

           }

       }}
   ```

Hope it helps.